# $cordovaSQLite not finding table

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i'm working on an app with ionic, and I have an json file that i would need to write on it, but i've researched and saw its impossible, so i'm migratin to $cordovaSQLite to be able to write...

the problem is, i have the populated db on the www folder, and the folowing code calls for it:

```
.factory('db', function($cordovaSQLite) {
return {
    get: function() {
        var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "adivinha.db", createFromLocation: 1, createFromResource: 1});
        query = "SELECT * FROM questionType";
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, res){
                alert("oi");
            });
        }, function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        });
    }
}
})
```

but every time i run this it goes to the error saying that the table questionType does not exists... what am i doing wrong? I've searched the hole web for that and couldn't find the answer...

Comment: What do you get when you log the error ?

Comment: that the table doesnt exists

Comment: I fixed the first problem, now the problem is that the function that calls it gets undefined because it is taking a little longer than it should:/

Comment: You then should create a new question for this new problem, and add here the solution for the "not finding table" problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, i`ve just remove the app from the phone and it worked